# How to drag and drop items both in the RecyclerView and into a View

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with GridLayout that resides below an ImageView.
How can I drag and drop items in the RecyclerView and from the RV into the ImageView. I tried using ItemTouchHelper, but it only works inside the RecyclerView and the item cannot be dragged into the ImageView.